# Inaginary error function with imaginary operand

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-integration, error-function

Wikipedia has [the following definition for imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function):

$$\textrm{erfi}(x) = i ~\textrm{eft}(ix)  $$

I have two questions,

1. Is the following correct?

$$\textrm{erfi}(ix) = i ~\textrm{eft}(i^2 x)  $$

2. What about this one? Where to start in simplfying this?

$$\textrm{erfi}(i\sqrt{i} x) = ? $$

Answer (score 1):

The definition you provide from Wikipedia is misleading, and possibly inaccurate. More appropriately stated, the error function of a purely imaginary number, say $z=iy$ is given by

$$\text{erf}(iy)=\frac{2i}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^y e^{t^2}=\frac{2i}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{y^2}D(y)$$

Reference: K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer. Chapter 7 covers the error function.

The two questions you pose must be answered in the context of these definitions.

In my work with the error function of *complex* arguments, I have programmed up the equations given in Abramowitz, M., Stegun, I.A., 1964. *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables*. Dover, New York, Equation 7.1.29.